# Can't restore latest WhatsApp Backup to new device

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

My iPhone 11 went in for damage assessment on 9 January, which is when I did an iCloud backup of everything. The same day I pulled out my iPhone 7 and restored from iCloud to get all my WhatsApp messages onto that phone. Today I received a replacement iPhone 11 and restored the new phone from the iCloud backup of my iPhone 7.

My problem is that WhatsApp will only restore the messaged from 9 January - the iCloud back I made on the previous iPhone 11.

I don't want to lose all the messaged that I received between 9 January and today.

I have tried deleting the WhatsApp backup on iCloud and recreating from the iPhone 7, but somehow the backup restore that the new iPhone 11 finds is from 9 January.

I deleted the old phone from iCloud and re-attempted above, with no differents.

I reduced the size of the WhatsApp backup on iPhone 7 by removing a lot of media and then confirmed on both phones that the WhatsApp part of iCloud storage is the reduced size.

Research indicates that there are 2 backups for WhatsApp - one for the application itself stored on iCloud and another for iCloud backup. I think that my problem is the previous iPhone 11's iCloud backup.

Guidance, help, please.

Comment: Did you have the iPhone 7 do iCloud backups of WhatsApp?  It looks like the only backup on iCloud is the one you did on the iPhone 11 before it went for service.  Did other apps have data/backups after Jan 9?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 7 did do iCloud backups too, including for WhatsApp. It is difficult to definitively say that other Apps did backup from iPhone 7 to restore on 11 because it is only on WhatsApp that you would notice that there was a dead period - that your snapshot is old. I have now completely deleted the old iPhone 11 backup and somehow WhatsApp can still restore the 9 Jan backup - I cannot fathom where it is storing 2.3GB.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: Delete iCloud backup for my previous iPhone 11, then reset new iPhone 11 and restore from the iPhone 7 backup, which is now the only backup. This worked.